# How can I transfer an Extentions from one Chrome on one PC to another Chrome on other PC

Tags: google-chrome

I do know that the EXT in Chrome are saved in `%AppData%\Local\Goolge\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions` . but when I do a copy of one EXT from one PC/Chrome to another I can not see the EXT in the icons right next to the URL. Must I copy something else? Can anyone here give an useful advice. THe EXT is not available anymore on the net. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution: You have to switch to develope-mode and click on the `Load unpacked extension` Then go to the directory where the Manifest is stored and load the extension.[image: load folder with extension]